# Connection closed with public key

Tags: linux, ssh, public-key

I have some troubles with public key in SSH.

I want to connect a client A to a server B in SSH, without passphrase. 
I've 2 users in each machine: root and mysql.

The ssh connection by public key from A to B with root is okay.
Now, I want to do the same thing with the user mysql, but it doesn't work.

I created a key on A with this command:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Then, I copy the key from ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub (Machine A,user mysql) and paste it on ~/.ssh/authorized_keys (Machine B,user mysql).

When I try, from machine A, user mysql to connect  on machine B by ssh like this:

```
ssh machineB
```

I got the following issue:

Connection closed by [ip address of machine B]

I did the ssh -vvv machineB and had:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug3: Trying to reverse map address xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure. Minor code may provide more information
Unknown code krb5 195

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure. Minor code may provide more information Unknown code krb5 195

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure. Minor code may provide more information Unknown code krb5 195

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mysql/.ssh/identity
debug3: no such identity: /home/mysql/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/mysql/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
Connection closed by machineB IP addr
```

Permissions on machine A:

```
drwx------  2 mysql mysql  4096 Nov 30 11:31 .
drwxr-xr-x 79 mysql mysql 28672 Nov 30 14:08 ..
-rw-------  1 mysql mysql   407 Oct  9  2009 authorized_keys
-rw-------  1 mysql mysql   668 Nov 24 16:18 id_dsa
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql mysql   608 Nov 24 16:18 id_dsa.pub
-rw-------  1 mysql mysql  1675 Nov 30 10:08 id_rsa
-rwx------  1 mysql mysql  1675 May 25  2010 id_rsa.archive
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql mysql   400 Nov 30 10:08 id_rsa.pub
-rwxrwxr-x  1 mysql mysql   400 May 25  2010 id_rsa.pub.archive
-rwxrwxr-x  1 mysql mysql  8068 Nov  6 09:20 known_hosts
```

Permissions on machine B:

```
drwx------  2 mysql mysql  4096 Nov 30 11:47 .
drwxr-xr-x 25 mysql apache 4096 Nov 30 12:13 ..
-rw-------  1 mysql mysql  1424 Nov 30 10:10 authorized_keys
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql mysql  3128 Jun  1  2011 known_hosts
```

Comment: Do you have some logs on machine B `/var/log/auth.log` ? You can as well make `ssh -vvv machineB` to have verbose

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I answered as an "Answer", because it was too long for a comment ;)

Comment: Can you check the permissions on .ssh folder for mysql. `ls -al ~/.ssh/`

Comment: Sure. I put results on the question.

Comment: what does `getent passwd mysql` say? usually a standard-mysql user doesn't have a home directory, so sshd wouldn't know where to look for the .ssh directory, and mysql probably doesn't have a login shell either.

Comment: @mata thank you for your answer but here, mysql is an entire user. mysql has a shell, an home, etc... Here is the result of the getent passwd mysql:

    mysql:x:27:48:MySQL Server:/home/mysql:/bin/bash

Comment: :^) you can restart sshd on machineB with the flag -d for debug mode.

Comment: I can't make it because the server machineB can't be restart at my company, and if the debug goes wrong, it will make big troubles. DO you have any other idea?

Comment: You can check the sshd config file one the server. And look for allow users or deny users or other similar config. The file is in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Answer (score 1):

This message could have multiple explanations.

For me, the server was closing the connection after the client offered a public key:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: blahkey RSA SHA256:V6g54p//KqUOYHbR3KQ4jK+rL9jZEBrZIizKTLmO+aE explicit
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
Connection closed by 2600::1 port 22
```

The sshd logs showed nothing at `LogLevel INFO`. When I set `LogLevel VERBOSE`, the server only logged the connection, but did not log a failure reason or the disconnection at all.

My system was in a messed up state and I finally thought to check `dmesg`. Sure enough:

```
[13146519.317245] sshd[13970]: segfault at 30 ip b77bceaf sp bf8a1c80 error 4 in libssl.so.1.0.0[b777c000+6b000]
[13146519.317269] Code: c3 8d 76 00 8d bc 27 00 00 00 00 83 ec 2c 89 74 24 20 8b 74 24 30 89 5c 24 1c 89 7c 24 24 8b 7c 24 38 89 6c 24 28 8b 6c 24 34 <8b> 46 14 e8 6a 26 fd ff 81 c3 3d d1 02 00 85 c0 74 05 3b 46 10 74
```

`sshd` was segfaulting. I needed to update packages server-side to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Interestingly I was able to log in via `ssh <username>@<hostname> -p <port>` I checked into logs as suggested by Clempat in `/var/log/auth.log` where I found this:

```
Sep 20 10:31:45 vbndx-VirtualBox sshd[3559]: Invalid user vega.bondx from 10.0.2.2 port 52637
```

It seems that my ssh config file was set up such as the global option

```
   Host *
   User vega.bondx
```

precedes

```
   Host virt
   User vegabondx
```

from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/718346/openssh-ssh-config-host-specific-overrides-not-working) I realized that the order is important. and the Host * option should be at the end.